# How can I set JwtEncodingContext with extra information in Spring authorization server

Tags: spring, spring-oauth2

My use case is that I have some extra details(user and client) that I need to populate in token claims generated by Spring Authorization Server. For this information, I don't want to call external APIs as they are already called during authentication and it would be an overhead if I call again in

```
OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtTokenCustomizer() {

        return context -> {}}
```

I was hoping to explicitly set in context so I can use the details from context and add in claims.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?